# How to load a csv file in flutter from startup/automatically?

Tags: flutter

I have a .csv file in my assets file I want to load to display data within my app.

I've found multiple examples online but they all require the user to press a button. Here's what I've been doing:

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  // This function is triggered when the floating button is pressed
  void _loadCSV() async {
    final rawData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/myfile.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> listData = const CsvToListConverter().convert(rawData);
    print(listData[0]);
    setState(() {
      _data = listData;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Various stuff including a ListView.builder

 //at the bottom
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _loadCSV, child: const Icon(Icons.add)),
    );
```

This works fine but you need to press the floating button for the data to show up.

I also tried sticking the loadCSV, which worked, but I feel like is the wrong way to solve this as then it's continuously loading the file?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    //_loadCSV();
```

Comment: try using FutureBuilder also you can  check   initState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply put the call to `_loadCSV()` into your initState() method.
if your app can't do anything without the CSV you could probably even load it in your `main` method before calling `runApp` and just pass your data to the widget..

like

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final data = _loadCSV(); // turn it into a top level function and return the values.
  runApp(child: HomePage(data: data));
}
```

this way the loading happens while the splash screen is still visible and as soon as the app is displayed data is available..

Comment: Thanks! The initState was the functionality I was looking for but didn't know what it was called.